Adding Markers to Maps Using the TomTom Static Image API
I am working with the TomTom Static Image API to generate map images for my flutter application. I would like to display markers (pins) on specific locations within the map. However, I couldn’t find detailed documentation or examples on how to implement markers in the static images.
How can I add markers to maps generated using the TomTom Static Image API? Are there specific parameters or formats that need to be included in the API request URL to achieve this?
I tried using the TomTom Static Image API with a standard URL format to generate map images. Here's the URL I used: https://api.tomtom.com/map/1/staticimage?key=<TomTom_API_Key>&zoom=16&center=37.4219983,-122.084&format=jpg&layer=basic&style=main&width=600&height=300
I was expecting to be able to add markers (pins) at specific coordinates on the map by appending the relevant parameters, but I couldn't find any documentation or clear instructions on how to include markers.
Note: I just need to show the marker (pin) on the map. there is no issue within the app code.
This is the code i used to display a image of the map within my app:
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:favorite_places/models/place.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class LocationInput extends StatefulWidget {
  const LocationInput({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<LocationInput> createState() {
    return _LocationInputState();
  }
}

class _LocationInputState extends State<LocationInput> {
  PlaceLocation? _pickedLocation;
  var _isGettingLocation = false;

  String get locationImage {
    if (_pickedLocation == null) {
      return '';
    }

    final lat = _pickedLocation!.latitude;
    final lng = _pickedLocation!.longitude;

    return 'https://api.tomtom.com/map/1/staticimage?key={API_KEY}&zoom=4&center=$lng,$lat&format=jpg&layer=basic&style=main&width=600&height=300&view=Unified&language=en-GB';
  }

  void _getLocation() async {
    Location location = new Location();

    bool serviceEnabled;
    PermissionStatus permissionGranted;
    LocationData locationData;

    serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
      if (!serviceEnabled) {
        return;
      }
    }

    permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
    if (permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
      if (permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted) {
        return;
      }
    }

    setState(() {
      _isGettingLocation = true;
    });

    locationData = await location.getLocation();
    final lat = locationData.latitude;
    final lng = locationData.longitude;

    if (lat == null || lng == null) {
      return;
    }

    final url = Uri.parse(
        'https://api.tomtom.com/search/2/reverseGeocode/$lat,$lng.json?key={API_key}&radius=100');

    final response = await http.get(url);
    final resData = json.decode(response.body);
    final address = resData['addresses'][0]['address']['freeformAddress'];

    print(lat);
    print(lng);

    setState(() {
      _pickedLocation =
          PlaceLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: lng, address: address);
      _isGettingLocation = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget previewContent = Text(
      'No location chosen',
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge!.copyWith(
            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground,
          ),
    );

    if (_pickedLocation != null) {
      previewContent = Image.network(
        locationImage,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
      );
    }

    if (_isGettingLocation) {
      previewContent = const CircularProgressIndicator();
    }

    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 170,
          width: double.infinity,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
              width: 1,
              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary.withOpacity(0.2),
            ),
          ),
          child: previewContent,
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            TextButton.icon(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.location_on),
              label: const Text('Get Current Location'),
              onPressed: _getLocation,
            ),
            TextButton.icon(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.map),
              label: const Text('Select on Map'),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}


The static image api does not have any way to add markers. https://developer.tomtom.com/map-display-api/documentation/raster/static-image  You would need to add these to the image that is returned yourself.

you are adding the markers into the google map. Lat. lng.  are just use to do focus on selected location. After getting Lat. Lng. from API pass those values to the function below
try this.
Map<MarkerId, Marker> _markers = {};// store markers first

void _addMarker(
      LatLng position, String title, String imagePath) async {
    final markerId = MarkerId(title);
    BitmapDescriptor customIcon;
    try {
      customIcon = await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
        const ImageConfiguration(size: Size(48, 48)),
        imagePath,//  icon image from asset make sure it's in PNG.
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error loading custom icon for $title: $e");
      customIcon = BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker;
    }

    final marker = Marker(
      markerId: markerId,
      position: position,
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: title),
      icon: customIcon,
    );

    setState(() {
      _markers[markerId] = marker;
    });
  }

and your map will have these markers to show
 GoogleMap(
          markers: Set<Marker>.of(_markers.values),
          onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
            mapController = controller;
            mapController.moveCamera(
              CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
                CameraPosition(
                  target: _currentLocation,
                  zoom: _zoomLevel,
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
            target: _currentLocation,
            zoom: _zoomLevel,
          ),
        ),

now just call _addMaker function and your map will have the markers
this is the package I used
 google_maps_flutter

do let me know if you need any help

Yes, I know how to add them to Google Maps, but here I want them in TomTom Maps.
